# How to add an image to a path in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I bought an EPS and I want to add an image to a path. Is it possible?

This is here the path. And an British flag I want to add / render on it.

[image]

A very bad resolution, but something like this:
[image]

Comment: do you want the image to be on the path or into it?

Comment: I want the image in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have two choices:

1-cut the shape you want and past inside using the draw inside mode (Shift + D)

2-using clipping mask by making the mask over the object you want and go to `Object>Cilpping Mask> Make`